# Jolt to Transform JSON Array and change labels

Tags: arrays, json, transformation, jolt

I have a JSON as below.

```json
[
  {
    "CATENTRY_ID": "3074457345616677728",
    "USAGE": "1",
    "LANGUAGE_ID": "-1",
    "STOREENT_ID": "10051",
    "ATTRTYPE_ID": "STRING",
    "ATTR_ID": "7741124012283333360",
    "ATTR_SEQUENCE": "0"
  },
  {
    "CATENTRY_ID": "3074457345616677729",
    "USAGE": "1",
    "LANGUAGE_ID": "-1",
    "STOREENT_ID": "10051",
    "ATTRTYPE_ID": "STRING",
    "ATTR_ID": "7741124012283333360",
    "ATTR_SEQUENCE": "0"
  }
]
```

Using JOLT operation I want to convert as below. Rename CATENTRY_ID to **ProductId** and **remove** USAGE from JSON

```json
[
  {
    "ProductId": "3074457345616677728",
    "LANGUAGE_ID": "-1",
    "STOREENT_ID": "10051",
    "ATTRTYPE_ID": "STRING",
    "ATTR_ID": "7741124012283333360",
    "ATTR_SEQUENCE": "0",
  },
  {
    "ProductId": "3074457345616677729",
    "LANGUAGE_ID": "-1",
    "STOREENT_ID": "10051",
    "ATTRTYPE_ID": "STRING",
    "ATTR_ID": "7741124012283333360",
    "ATTR_SEQUENCE": "0",
  }
]
```

I have used below operation to achieve same, However rename is not working in my case.**strong text**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&0",
        "LANGUAGE_ID": "LANGUAGE_ID"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close, just filter for the attributes with trailing `_ID`, and leading `ATTR_` in order to exempt the attribute with key name `USAGE` within the current shift transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*_ID|ATTR_*": "[&1].&",
        "CATENTRY_ID": "[&1].ProductId"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This Spec will give you the solution you want you require 2 operations to do it :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#2].&",
        "CATENTRY_ID": "[#2].ProductId"
      }
    }
    }, {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "USAGE": ""
      }
    }
    }

]
```